# Mysqldb not installing in python2 virtual env

Tags: python, mysql, linux, mysql-python

I am trying to install Mysqldb in python2 env and have tried the following things.

Thus was the initial error :

```
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
   compilation terminated.
   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Then I tried these

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

There was no change in error
and  then I tried this 

`sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev`

and error now is

```
 In file included from _mysql.c:44:
   /usr/include/mariadb/my_config.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
    #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
     ^~~~~~~
   In file included from _mysql.c:46:
   /usr/include/mariadb/mysql.h:444:3: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
      MYSQL_CLIENT_PLUGIN_HEADER
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   _mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject_ping’:
   _mysql.c:2005:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ {aka ‘struct st_mysql’} has no member named ‘reconnect’
     if ( reconnect != -1 ) self->connection.reconnect = reconnect;
                                            ^
   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Can some one help set up mysqldb in python2 virtualenv?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361162/installing-mysqldb-for-python-2-7-returns-error?rq=1).

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.4.6
```

It works.